# Spinning arrow after submission – happens only in one form (one step)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, contact-form-7, internal-server-error

I have created a multi-step form – a research questionnaire in WP using Contact Form 7.
During the fourth step, after clicking the submit button the arrows start spinning and nothing happens. This step contains the form with many conditional fields, however, after removing them the problem remained.

I have checked the console. After submitting such an error shows.
jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4 POST feedback 500 (Internal Server Error)
It doesn’t show on other forms (steps).

I tried both:
define( ‘WPCF7_LOAD_JS’, false);
define( ‘WPCF7_LOAD_JS’, false);

add_filter( ‘wpcf7_load_js’, ‘__return_false’ );
add_filter( ‘wpcf7_load_css’, ‘__return_false’ );

Arrow disappears, submission button works fine, however the form is not moving to the next step.

I have also used define (‘WP_DEBUG’, false) – nothing has changed.
I have only necessary plugins (turning them off does nothing).
New .htaccess was created. Still nothing.

My active plugins:
Contact Form 7, Contact Form 7 Conditional Fields, Contact Form 7 Multi-Step Forms, Contact Form CFDB7, Cookie Notice, Orphans

Theme: Hemingway (changing it to default does not bring any effect)

Generally the whole form is rather slow, but this one step is more problematic.

Any ideas?Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to deal with the problem by myself. There was a problem with a free version of  Contact Form 7 Multi-Step Forms and cookies -  during the submission cookie size limit was exceeded and it made impossible to move to the next step.  With a Pro version everything works fine.